# Default template engine in codeiginter?

Tags: codeigniter, template-engine

Can anyone tell me which template engine **codeiginter** used by default.line other framework like laravel.

Answer (score 1):

[Template Parser Class](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/parser.html)

CodeIgniter does not require you to use this class since using pure PHP in your view pages lets them run a little faster.

I would suggest if you really want to use a template engine to have a look at these links:

If you're looking for a simple and easy way to implement Twig Template Engine in your project (by CodeIgniter version):

- CI 2.x:

  - http://edmundask.github.io/codeigniter-twiggy/
  - https://github.com/dilantha/codeigniter-twig/
- CI 3.x:

  - https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-ss-twig